# Split string into same consecutive characters

Tags: c++, beginner, strings

## Description

- Splits a string into a vector of strings that has consecutive same characters

  - Examples in test cases below (`"5500025"` --> `["55", "000", "2", "5"]`)
- Only ASCII needs to be supported
- In case of style/formatting issues, I am using https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/

## Compile

- `gcc -std=c++17 file.cpp`
- I'm not committed to C++17 (using it for `std::string_view`), so if C++20 or some other version makes it significantly easier, I can switch to that

## Test cases

- Provided in `main()`

  - `"AAABBCDDDDAAEE5"` --> `["AAA", "BB", "C", "DDDD", "AA", "EE", "5"]`
  - `""` --> `[]`

## Code

### `file.cpp` ([tio.run](https://tio.run/##jVNhb5swEP3Or7hRaSJKUq0fqkk0VCId2o/YJss1B7EKtoVN2i3ir4/ZEAg0STVLWPbzu@d354Mptc4Za9sbLlhRpwgbpk2aYvbonSAutamQllPMIlzkU2SPzMjq0fOsQBj2u023Hrh5JWtF@h1hslRSoDA6mJDInuMrcKFqcyQu4OABXNOETtOuHjzL4hkE09jbAkVudsECogi@9EoAFZq6EpNIgMYb7tD8DxIDSmqwIe7sdccLhMAhnyKYXB6GwoKD6jRa4JshnUR35MbMVsZFSjJeaUOENERmM9c/bOSvVWdhCXeLLrO5foUKqbEGx4vWjn5kuiqcHHxgGU5Cl6t2VHXMptceinarar0jz5S9TF8v6PVWcJbOYkijL@xgb6z92ZtYdC95ClUtyIASg9qcd4tDCaMaiaAlrsaSvxsfdtnVKCaFNtfb7zO@KQtjOpr8z361Rbj2O8y6/2EQY7I2sNm8y9YhPiiqNaahXdltx36WsqCF2tFZXvY0OBmI4IJ5p/dT@N0DcGGgpFwEfU7nT@F/R4EVLcD58Vfgx3G83T59syOOk@Tev1zWg@M5@nbr5ic3uZhewc1J4uZ7v@nyv3BxUirze7zWfoem77BjI9k/t2nbvywraK7bta1JxJbLu6//AA))

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string>
group_string_components(std::string_view input_string) {
  std::vector<std::string> grouping;

  if (input_string.length() == 0) {
    return grouping;
  }

  std::size_t pos = 0;
  while (pos != std::string::npos) {
    std::size_t next_pos =
        input_string.find_first_not_of(input_string[pos], pos + 1);

    std::size_t repeat = next_pos - pos;

    if (next_pos == std::string::npos) {
      repeat = input_string.length() - pos;
    }

    grouping.push_back(std::string(repeat, input_string[pos]));

    pos = next_pos;
  }

  return grouping;
}

void run_grouping_test(std::string_view test_case_name,
                       std::string_view input_string,
                       const std::vector<std::string> &expected_grouping) {
  std::vector<std::string> grouping = group_string_components(input_string);
  std::cout << test_case_name << " passed: " << std::boolalpha
            << (grouping == expected_grouping) << "\n";
}

int main() {
  run_grouping_test("General case", "AAABBCDDDDAAEE5",
                    {"AAA", "BB", "C", "DDDD", "AA", "EE", "5"});
  run_grouping_test("Empty case", "", {});

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it a bound task that you need to return a 'std::vector<std::string>'?

Answer (score 4):

#### Avoid memory allocations, Part 1.

Your function takes a `std::string_view` in input, why does it return a `std::string`?

It would be better to return a `std::string_view` (referencing the input), and leave it up to the caller to turn it into a `std::string` if they so wish.

#### Use `string_view` functionality.

For consuming input, in a parsing, there are two great functions in `std::string_view`:

- `substr`, which allows creating a substring.
- `remove_prefix`, which allows popping the first N characters.

Rather than tracking the offset on your own, it simplifies the code quite a bit to use those two functions and "consume" your input as you go.

#### Putting it altogether.

A simple rewrite, with the above:

```
auto group_string_components(std::string_view input)
    -> std::vector<std::string_view>
{
    std::vector<std::string_view> grouping;

    if (input.empty()) {
        return grouping;
    }

    while (true) {
        std::size_t next = input.find_first_not_of(input[0], 1);

        grouping.push_back(input.substr(0, next));

        if (next == std::string_view::npos) {
            return grouping;
        }

        input.remove_prefix(next);
    }
}
```

#### Avoid memory allocations, Part 2.

There is, however, at least one remaining memory allocation: the `vector`. And actually, it's probably going to lead to *several* allocations, as the `vector` may internally need to reallocate a few times.

Do you actually *need* to materialize the collection? `group_string_components` certainly *doesn't*: it never looks back.

This suggests that instead of returning a `vector`, `group_string_components` should instead return either a pair of iterators, or, with C++20, ranges. Actually, C++23 should offer a `ranges::chunk_by_view` which would be ideal here... but in the mean time, it needs to be coded manually.

I'll show off the iterator case, there is a trick with the `advance` function (which has to be called in the constructor) that is good to remember:

```
class group_component_iterator {
public:
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
    using value_type = std::string_view;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using pointer = value_type*;
    using reference = value_type&;

    group_component_iterator() noexcept = default;

    group_component_iterator(std::string_view v) noexcept : tail(v) {
         if (!this->tail.empty()) {
             this->advance();
         }
    }

    pointer operator->() { return &this->current; }

    reference operator*() { return this->current; }

    group_component_iterator& operator++() {
        this->advance();
        return *this;
    }

    group_component_iterator operator++(int) {
        auto tmp = *this;
        this->advance();
        return tmp;
    }

    bool operator==(group_component_iterator const& other) {
        //  Do not use `std::string_view` operator ==, as it compares the content
        //  which is potentially expensive.
        return (this->current.empty() && other.current.empty())
            || (this->current.data() == other.current.data()
                && this->current.size() == other.current.size()
                && this->tail.data() == other.tail.data()
                && this->tail.size() == other.tail.size());
    }

    bool operator!=(group_component_iterator const& other) {
        return !(*this == other);
    }

private:
    void advance() {
        assert(!tail.empty());

        auto next = tail.find_first_not_of(tail[0], 1);
        current = tail.substr(0, next);

        tail.remove_prefix(std::min(next, tail.size()));
    }

    std::string_view current;
    std::string_view tail;
};
```

The core of the logic has moved into the iterator, so the function is now simple:

```
auto group_string_components(std::string_view input)
    -> std::pair<group_component_iterator, group_component_iterator>
{
    return std::make_pair(group_component_iterator(input), group_component_iterator());
}
```

*Note: untested code.*

There are two advantages to using an iterator/range approach:

- Laziness:

  - If the caller only cares about the first 5 groups, then the others are never used.
  - If the caller only uses 1 group at a time, then the others are not materialized *simultaneously*, which saves on memory.
- No allocations.

Comment: Looks like we had a lot of the same observations, including `remove_prefix()` and `group_by_view()`.

Comment: @TobySpeight: Indeed; your answer wasn't there when I started on mine, otherwise I wouldn't have bothered. Your use of sink iterator as an argument leads to much simpler code, too.

Comment: I saw yours appear when I was halfway through writing mine, but decided not to read it until I finished.  I like your idea of demonstration of a custom iterator; it's more complex, but quite educational.

Comment: I had hoped to be able to use the output iterator to assign to both string-views and string objects, but failed because conversion from string-view to string is (rightly) `explicit`.

Comment: I haven't used iterators a lot, much less creating my own iterators. So I have a question: why do you `return make_pair(iterator(input), iterator())` instead of just `return iterator(input)`? Based on my understanding, the second iterator has no functionality.

Comment: @TobySpeight Considering constructing from const char* is implicit, why does costructing from a view being explicit make sense?

Comment: Good question @Deduplicator.  I think it's the other way around - constructing a new string object from a view ought to be explicit (involves memory allocation, so could throw), and so should constructing from chars.  But the latter constructor goes right back to the very first C++, before `explicit` was invented.  I think if it were written now, `std::string::string(const char*)` _would_ be explicit.

Comment: @FromTheStackAndBack: Iterators in C++ come in pair, as they are modeled after pointers in C. It's not enough to know where to start, you also need to know where to stop. A typical `for` loop with iterators is `for (; it != end; ++it)`. For encapsulation purposes, it's better to provide the pair of iterators to the user in some way (begin and end), rather than require the user to know how to construct the end iterator.

Comment: @FromTheStackAndBack: adding to Matthieu's explanation, when you get to C++20, you'll find that the concept of an _iterator pair_ (more accurately, an iterator and a _sentinel_) is the founding principle of the Ranges library.  It will definitely be useful to you if you're already thinking in those terms.

Answer (score 4):

Nice tidy code, and you've provided a test - that's good.  You didn't mention warning options when compiling; I used `g++-12 -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds -Wconversion  -Weffc++  -Wuseless-cast` and it was clean.

### Interface

Taking input as a `std::string_view` is perfect - no need to copy any character data.  However, we forgot to include the `<string_view>` header (`<string>` isn't sufficient if we want portable code).  We might want to generalise it to accept any character type, using template `std::basic_string_view<CharT>`.

Consider returning a collection of views, and leave it to the caller to decide whether to construct string objects from these.

The return type of the function might be a constraint in some use cases - not everyone wants a `std::vector`, and it might be hard for the allocator to find sufficient contiguous storage when the result is large.  We could provide a version that accepts an output iterator - users could then use a `std::back_insert_iterator` into any kind of collection, or even a `std::ostream_iterator` for full streaming without using any storage.

### Implementation

We're using the wrong `npos` constant - we should be using `std::string_view::npos`.

We don't actually need the `pos` index, if instead we shorten the view by advancing its start point, so that we're always looking at the beginning of the string (note, this is cheap with a view, but very costly with a string object).  We can use the `remove_prefix()` member function:

```
while (!input_string.empty()) {
    auto count = input_string.find_first_not_of(input_string.front());
    if (count == input_string.npos) {
        count = input_string.size();
    }

    grouping.emplace_back(input_string.substr(0, count));
    input_string.remove_prefix(count);
}
```

This has the additional advantage that we don't need a separate path to handle  empty input - that naturally happens with this loop.

As user [Deduplicator](/users/42409) observed, because the `npos` value is very large, we can use `std::min()` to restrict it to the string's size:

```
while (!input_string.empty()) {
    auto count = std::min(input_string.size(),
                          input_string.find_first_not_of(input_string.front()));
    *iter++ = input_string.substr(0, count);
    input_string.remove_prefix(count);
}
```

---

## Modified code

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

template<typename CharT,
         typename Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>,
         typename Iter>
auto
group_string_components(std::basic_string_view<CharT, Traits> input,
                        Iter iter)
{
    while (!input.empty()) {
        auto count = std::min(input.size(),
                              input.find_first_not_of(input.front()));
        *iter++ = input.substr(0, count);
        input.remove_prefix(count);
  }

  return iter;
}

template<typename CharT,
         typename Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>>
auto
group_string_components(std::basic_string_view<CharT, Traits> input)
{
    std::vector<std::basic_string_view<CharT, Traits>> grouping;
    group_string_components(input, std::back_inserter(grouping));
    return grouping;
}
```

If we had C++20, we could use constraints to restrict the `Iter` type, and with C++23, we might use `std::ranges::chunk_by_view` to split in this way.

Answer (score 3):

You could convert the `while` loop to a `for` loop:

```
for (std::size_t pos = 0, next_pos; pos != std::string::npos; pos = next_pos) {
```

The main reason to do that is to limit the `pos` variable to the loop body, it's not used outside.

---

I think `input_string.empty()` is more idiomatic than `input_string.length() == 0`.

---

For each grouping,
the loop body checks if the end of the string was reached or not.
You could avoid the extra conditional by counting the repeats yourself,
instead of using `find_first_not_of`,
at the expense of duplicating a `grouping.push_back(...)`.

```
std::size_t repeat = 0;
char prev = input_string[0];

for (auto c : input_string) {
  if (c == prev) {
    repeat++;
  } else {
    grouping.push_back(std::string(repeat, prev));
    prev = c;
    repeat = 1;
  }
}

grouping.push_back(std::string(repeat, prev));
```

Comment: emplace_back is a thing! empty isn't only more idiomatic, it better expresses intent and can be more efficient for some other containers.